# Keep the original ratio in a thumbnail image

Tags: images

I’m using a thumbnail size of 100 * 60 in my blog, but sometimes I want to use square images.

Is it possible to use a Wordpress plugin or CSS to make it fits by adding background in the sides to keep the original ratio of the image?

Example:

1. Original image size : 120 x 120
2. Add extra white/transparent background to make it at the thumbnail ratio : 200x120 
   *so 40 pixels on the right and the left on the original image so it’s centred*
3. Reduce the image size from 200*120 to 100*60.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Reference:](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-size/) `background-size` can stretch a background image proportionally using `cover` or `contain`. Check out this [Demo](https://davidwalsh.name/background-size).

HTML

```
<div class="square"></div>  
<div class="rec"></div>
```

CSS

```
.rec, .square {
  border: solid red 1px;
  background-color:black;
  background: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&txt=120×120&w=120&h=120");
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
}
.rec {
  width:100px;
  height:60px;
}
.square {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

The remaining space with `contain` will be transparent so just put it in a container with a background color set.